# how to make images in my webpages not downloadable

Tags: image, download, html

I am wondering how to prevent people from Save image as.. by right-click images on my webpages.

I was thinking about disable right-click, but it seems I have to write javascript code. Is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: Even if the image as not downloadable, what would stop the user from just making a screenshot while viewing the page and then cutting the image out of that screenshot?

Answer (score 10):

The simple answer is "you cannot do that".  You might be able to put something on the server side that will check the referer before serving the image, but even that is not 100% guaranteed.  Moreover, even if you did manage somehow to prevent this, nothing would prevent somebody from taking a screenshot of the browser page and then cropping the image out of it.

I think a much better approach would be to have a server-side url rewriting and processing of the images to add some sort of a visible watermark identifying the images as owned by you and saving a proper copyright information in the EXIF information.

Answer (score 5):

There's an easy solution for this which I used in my website. Just add `oncontextmenu="return false;"` attribute to the Image tag and you are done with it!
`<img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="Random image" oncontextmenu="return false;">`

This is my first question to be answered on stackoverflow, so please fair with me if I didn't use the right tools...

Answer (score 2):

You can make a div that is the same size and height as the image and then you can set the image as the background for that div. That will prevent people from directly downloading the image but they can still enter the url and download it from there. I made a tutorial on this myself right here: http://www.andytechguy.com/tutorials/html/how_to_nodownload/

Comment: Broken link: the website linked to no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the image URL is in the source code, the image is downloadable using the unix command wget, or anything similar. I'm not a javascript expert however, but I believe you could read the location of the photo from a text file instead of the URL being hard coded in the HTML. Then you could configure that text file to return a 403 (Permission denied) when attempted to view with whatever web server you are using. This still wouldn't stop screenshots though.

Something like this:

```
    <img src="some javascript to read text file">
```

Then have the text file contain:

```
    /path/to/obscurely/named/photo.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya, this isn't really possible.  Another option is to use Lightroom or something else to batch add watermarks.  Watermarks are the only option that I'm aware of that will almost completely protect you, because even the screenshot idea is not really possible unless they are a wizard in Photoshop.

In conclusion I think Lightroom or something else is your best and easiest shot of getting what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by converting the image format from jpg to svg...there are alot of converters online i.e https://convertio.co/jpg-svg/
After this you copy and paste the svg code into your html code to replace the jpg.