# How to make my web page images undownloadable in PHP?

Tags: php, security, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to make images in my webpages not downloadable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649680/how-to-make-images-in-my-webpages-not-downloadable)

I am working on a PHP project that has photo gallery of my client.My client has asked me to put restriction on the visitors to not to download his Photo gallery images/videos from the web pages i.e No one could save his photographic work(images ,multimedia,videos) by right clicking and by using "save as" option.Is there anyway i could restrict vistors of my website from downloading the contents from my PHP website??What steps i can take to prevent downloading of multimedia contents?I would appreciate if somebody could help me in this regard.

Comment: If they're visible to the client they're available to the client. You could maybe use a css-generated content to contain the images (which should prevent right-click -> save as, but they'll still be there in the resources).

Comment: As long as the images and videos are displayed in the page, they are automatically downloaded by the client, who can then save them, copy them as they want. All 'no-right-click' protections are completely ineffective against all but people who wouldn't want to save the images in the first place.

Comment: Every image and video you see on the Internet is downloaded before it becomes visible. There is eventually a way to save it. What image sites usually do is to display a low-quality version of its images and add watermarks on them.

Comment: You can intercept the right click event and cause the browser to not show the "save as" menu. But if the image is visible to the client, there's a way to download it -- otherwise, the client wouldn't be able to see it. The best you can do is make it more difficult to manually download. Some people solve this problem by redirecting to a different file name every page load, by burying the image in layers of HTML, or ... But it's just making the download more difficult and not protecting the file. If your client is concerned about this, they should post only low quality, watermarked images.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8649680/how-to-make-images-in-my-webpages-not-downloadable

Answer (score 1):

You can not prevent user from downloading images from your server. There are some tricks that can make it harder but if someone wants to steal media from a site, they will surely do.

For dumb users you can disable righ clicking ([already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)). But this and other methods are useless if the user disables Javascript or makes a simple screen capture.